# ReactJS - SVG - Interactive Timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, timeline

I would like to create an interactive timeline in React, as illustrated below:

[image: Timeline View]

General Info: The Timeline is showing items from a specified start date (top), until the current date (bottom). The items have each a date when they have occurred, and should be placed correctly within the available time-slots.

For the sake of simplicity, I would just like to focus on the following:
1. Drawing 
2. Calculate the position of items

**Could you please let me know if I'm on the right track with my following assumptions, or if you would suggest a different path?**

1. To draw the line I would use SVG without any further npm modules. The line will look the same no matter what start date(e.g. no matter if timeline starts 1991 or 2018)
2. I want to calculate the position of each item based on the following  factors:

2.1 One timeslot equals 1 day (e.g if the timeline shows 1/11 - 1/12, there will be 30 timeslots available - for the whole SVG line)

2.2 One timeslots space will be - 100% length of line / overall amount of days to show

2.3 Items position will be calculated based on days since timeline start, meaning an item happened on the 2/11 will be presented in the 2nd / 30 timeslot

**Would you also recommend to look back into basic math formulas again?** :-) 
Apart from that, if you have done something similar like this before and you could **let me know any possible banana skins** you are aware of, that would be much appreciated! Happy about ANY tips on this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 2.1 One timeslot equals 1 day (e.g if the timeline shows 1/11 - 1/12, there will be 30 timeslots available - for the whole SVG line)
here i think 23 timeslots should be there, can you explain how you got 30?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. To double check, I've just literally opened calendar and counted the weeks (1/11 - 7/11 = 7, 8/11 - 14/11 = 7, 15/11 - 21/11 = 7, 22/11 - 28/11 = 7, plus the 29/11 and the 30/11.
How did you come to 23? Sorry for any confusion
Did you count work days only? As a background, this timeline is for a social media app and it's actually showing memories the user had with certain events. So full weeks count :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked the look of this so I thought I'd throw together a quick demo for you using the [SVGGeometryElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement) to fetch the line length and points along it. It's a pretty handy little interface. Run the following snippet to see it in action:

```js
class SVGThingy extends React.Component {
  state = {
    points: [],
  };
  
  componentDidMount(){
    const lineLength = this.path.getTotalLength();
    const spanLength = lineLength / 30;
    const points = new Array(31).fill('')
      .map((p,i) => this.path.getPointAtLength(i * spanLength));
    this.setState({points})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg viewBox="0 0 240 200" width="240px" height="200px" >
        <path ref={p => this.path = p} fill="none" stroke="red" strokeWidth="1" d="M 5.3 34.7 C 5.3 34.7 238.6 -29.5 232.6 23 C 222.4 114.6 5.3 12.3 2.9 83.9 C 0.5 155.5 232.3 40 230.8 106.1 C 228.7 190.2 4.3 100 4.1 158.9 C 3.9 218.4 241.9 127.9 193 194.9"/>
        {this.state.points.map((p,i)=> (
          <circle cx={p.x} cy={p.y} r="3" stroke="black" strokeWidth="2" fill="white"/>
        ))}
      </svg>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <SVGThingy />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, apologies for the late reply. I could get a start today, and it worked out quite well. I have very much appreciated your effort putting this together! Helped me a lot to get an easy start! Thanks again!